# Is there a dua for when someone repeatedly vandalizes my car cover?

Tags: practical-islam, dua

I park my car right at the side of my house and cover it.  The previous year some one allegedly cut the cover and broke the side mirror intentionally and ran away. Last night they tried to do the same, but luckily I was in the house and went outside, and they went away.  I do not know them, but have seen their faces many times in the street. Is there any supplication that I can make against them?

I am really fed up with their daily routine of of destroying my car's cover; it is not right to dua against someone but, again, what should i do fight them?

Answer (score 1):

You can recite

> اللّهُـمَّ إِنا نَجْـعَلُكَ في نُحـورِهِـم، وَنَعـوذُ بِكَ مِنْ شُرورِهـمْ

O Allah, we ask You to restrain them by their necks and we seek refuge in You from their evil.[Abu Dawud 2/89]

and

> اللَّهُمَّ اكْفِنِيهِمْ بِماَ شِئْتَ

O Allah, suffice (i.e. protect) me against them however You wish [Muslim 4/2300]